# How to disable secure-file-priv MySQL Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

Guys I have an application that use SELECT OUTFILE to be used as cache for another application, so, it outputs straight to /dev/shm/some/folder.

As it runs on a background server, I have no issue disabling all mysql security, the option **secure_file_priv** isn't set in the my.ini but is default set by the version, how to disable this folder security?

```
[MySQL Version]
/usr/sbin/mysqld  Ver 5.7.12-0ubuntu1 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))

[Ubuntu Version]
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The mysql documentation on [secure_file_priv](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_secure_file_priv) states that the variable is set to a default, platform-specific filesystem location, to make it secure by default.

That said, you need to explicitly set the variable to an empty string in your configuration to disable this security feature.

For Ubuntu, edit the file `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` and add the following line at the end:

```
secure_file_priv=""
```

Then make sure to restart the service.

Comment: Thanks!! Actually I've made a workaround using only "/" instead of the path, assuming everypath were goingo to be inside of it.

Comment: On Workbench (after giving the password again), `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "secure_file_priv";` is still giving me `/var/lib/mysql-files/`, and I still can't `load data`.

Comment: You can't just put that line at the end of the file. It has to go under the `[mysqld]` heading.

Answer (score 2):

For me adding to the end of the above file didn't work.

I added it to the `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` file in the [mysqld] section and it worked.

You may be able to create that section in the above file and it also work, I didn't test it.

After the server re-start you can test with `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "secure_file_priv";` provided you have priveleve to do so.

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. You can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)